# Eliminate Flickering in C# WinForms Application

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, flicker

I am creating a `C# WinForm Application` (for a touch device "MS Surface Hub") using `Visual Studio 2013`. 
I have created two forms:

1. First form contains Introduction video (axWindowsMediaPlayer) which runs on form load
2. Second form contains Menu (Flash file)

If a user interrupts by touching the screen on Form 1, the Introduction video stops playing and moves to Form 2. Here is my code to achieve this:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer_ClickEvent(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_ClickEvent e)
    {
        Player.close();
        var menu = new Menu();
        menu.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        menu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

However when I checked the Transition from Form 1 to Form 2, I observed a `flicker effect` (i.e. I observed the back screen being displayed for a fraction of a second). How do I eliminate this effect? 
I went through a lot of questions on Stack Forums and also read a lot of blogs, but didn't found a working solution. I was suggested to use a `DoubleBuffered` property in my form, but it gave me the following Error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Another suggestion was to use `WS_EX_COMPOSITED 0x02000000L`, But I didn't found enough notes on how to accurately implement this in my code. A quote on this on MSDN:

> Paints all descendants of a window in bottom-to-top painting order using double-buffering. For more information, see Remarks. This cannot be used if the window has a class style of either CS_OWNDC or CS_CLASSDC.

I would like to know if there is a workaround for eliminating flicker effect.

Comment: How were you using `DoubleBuffered`? Also, note that certain flickering is unavoidable in WinForms (due to, in part, Microsoft's crippling of GDI/GDI+ in Windows Vista and later). If you're targeting a Surface Hub then you should be using XAML as your application's UI framework, not WinForms.

Comment: I was using DoubleBuffered inside the MediaPlayer Click function... this.DoubleBuffered... I also tried using it in InitializeForm() function

Comment: The way you use duoblebuffered is by setting it to true. `this.DoubleBuffered = true;`

Comment: ...but i don't think double-buffering is your problem. I think the problem is, that you hide hte existing form before you show the other one - so there is a fraction of a second where you are not showing anything. Could you perhaps try something as simple as moving the call to `this.Hide()` down below `menu.Show()`

Comment: There is generally speaking no magic to fix that and you will have to review your code to avoid unnecessary redrawing which requires experience and patience.

Comment: @JakobOlsen Where should I place this.DoubleBuffered = true ? In InitializeForm() or on Click Event? Your suggestion to move this.hide() below menu.show() has reduced flicker time but it is still visible. Thanks.

Comment: You should do it in InitializefForm. It only needs to be called once. Try it out - but i still don't think doublebuffering is what you're after.

Comment: I too believe that DoubleBuffered will not help my case, I am looking for other options as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved zero flickering by using `sendToBack` and `bringToFront` property of the form. I initially loaded both my forms in InitializeForm() function and then simply set these properties on my form on Touch event. By doing so the time to load a form i.e. using `.show()` and `.hide()` is eliminated.

**Note:** Both my forms are `static` and thus I can apply these properties. In a scenario where which form is to be loaded is decided dynamically, I am not sure whether this will give the desired result. Any better solutions are welcomed.